# Is there a way to make this jquery slider update POST values live?

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm using a slider to send values as POST to my server, however, they only update on mouse up.  Is there a way to POST repeatedly during a mouse down, as the slider is being dragged?

```
function changeBuzz(event, ui) { 
    $('#indicator').text(ui.value); 
    $.post('/buzz', { buzz: ui.value } ); 
}         

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#slider').slider({min: 0, max:8000, change:changeBuzz}); 
});
```

Comment: Please provide more information on which slider library / plugin you are using. Might be supported out the box.

Comment: jquery-ui.min.js and jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Please check this event [#event-slide](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide)

> Triggered on every mouse move during slide. The value provided in the
>   event as ui.value represents the value that the handle will have as a
>   result of the current movement. Canceling the event will prevent the
>   handle from moving and the handle will continue to have its previous
>   value.

But watch out with repeatedly ajax requests on every mouse movement. Make sure you create some interval while moving the mouse or something like this... And keep the `change` event to guaranty a final correct value.

Answer (score 0):

For capturing sliding use the inbuilt slide event which is triggered on every mouse move during slide.

```
$('#slider').slider({
  min: 0, 
  max:8000, 
  slide: changeBuzz
});
```

If you also want to capture the mousedown event maybe just use the standard jquery handler outside the plugin (untested code below). But you would have to manually create the objects needed for your function which is only actually UI

```
$('#slider').mouseDown(function(e){
    var event = {}
    var ui = $('#slider') // this might not be correct but you can find out what you need here
    changeBuzz(event,ui)
}
```

This should get you at least some of the way there